# Using Eclipse (with Debian) to modify applications from the official repository

Tags: linux, eclipse, debian, gtk

For a university project, I am trying to find a not so cumbersome way to effectively modify certain applications from the official Debian repository, such as eog. I want to clarify that I am unfamiliar with Linux and GTK. My idea was to be able to work comfortably in terms of finding variable and function definitions, trying step by step debugging while getting used to gtk+ and the application's source code. I tried to understand the code while working from the terminal, but in my opinion, it was a pain i* t** a**.

So far, I managed to install the application's build dependencies with

```
sudo apt build-dep eog
```

and I received the source-code with

```
apt-get source eog
```

After I installed eclipse, I tried to get gtk+ running with the minimum example [from the gtk+ reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html). I found a very useful easy explanation [here. It's the answer from Wed, 04 November 2015 12:51.](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1071791/)No problem so far. So in theory, I should be able to write GTK+ applications in Eclipse. But when I am trying to make a new project and include eog's .src and .h files, I am running into a mass of unresolved inclusions, missing header files, undefined references etc...

So I wanted to ask: Did anybody work on similar tasks and can provide some help? Or: Does anyone have a better idea maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody should come across this ever again: I found an alternative solution: When you download the source-files of eog, you will come across the [meson-build system](https://mesonbuild.com/). Eclipse supports C meson-build projects. I just copied all downloaded source files into the meson-build project in eclipse in could compile it right away.